# Which minimal Linux distro for RPi will fit on 16 MB SD card?

Tags: linux, operating-systems

This is my first question here, so please be kind.

I have an original RPi and a 16MB SD card, and I don't want to use another USB drive to run Linux from. Which tiny distro will fit entirely on this SD card? It should run entirely in RAM and have at least an SSH server and a package manager. There are Linux distros which fit even on a floppy, so 16MB should be just enough. Any solutions?

Comment: On the pi you have the unique issue of needing to load the vendor blobs off of the boot partition first.  Start by figuring out how big that needs to be.  Then look at really compact things like router distributions designed for devices with 4 or 8 MB of NAND flash on the board, and see how they do it - note in particular that they tend to store a compressed filesystem image and unpack to ram, sort of like modern desktops do with their initrd image, but without the later replacement by a disk-based root filesystem.

Comment: There is OpenWrt, which claims to fit on 8MB of flash, but the [RPi img file](http://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/brcm2708/generic/) is 50MB!

Comment: *"There are Linux distros which fit even on a floppy..."* -> I think you have been reading material that is at least a decade old.  These still exist -- their primary purpose was to serve as rescue disks, now I suppose it is about playing with antique hardware.  But I doubt you'll find one compiled for the pi if you haven't found one yet -- I'd guess they stopped making 16 MB cards years before the pi was even an idea, so there would be no real purpose in it.  Put another way, when you want something this peculiar, you might have to do it yourself...

Comment: ...Which would not be all that hard.  You should look into [busybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox), and/or distros based around busybox (tiny core is one example).   A lot of small scale embedded stuff is done that way.

Comment: I have a 32MB MMC card you can borrow :D

Answer (score 1):

[Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/6.x/armv6/release/6.0/) meets your requirement.

Comment: No, the unzipped IMG file is 18.3MB which is > 16MB

Comment: Look for a solution where only the boot blobs are uncompressed, while the Linux filesystem image is stored compressed and only gets uncompressed to RAM at runtime.  Also check for extra space in the boot partition.

Comment: You could also just splurge on a 32 MB card ;)  Actually that might be even harder to find.

Comment: I was able to fit in 16MB by deleting the files `start_x.elf` and `fixup_x.dat`.